# How to flatten hash for redis

Tags: arrays, hash, redis

In redis I need to create hset like this:

```
@redis.hset key, param1, val1, param2, val2
```

I have n hash:

```
params = {:a => "x", :b => "y"}
```

Flatten:

```
params = {:a => "x", :b => "y"}.flatten #=> [:a, "x", :b, "y"]
```

But I can't do this:

```
@redis.hmset key, params
```

Because it is passing an array:

```
@redis.hmset key, [:a, "x", :b, "y"]
```

I need do something with array to do this:

```
@redis.hmset key, :a, "x", :b, "y"
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the splat operator

```
@redis.hset key, *params
```

It will "unfold" the array into individual arguments.